# Trigonometry in coordinates not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, trignometry

I am trying to precalculate cos and sin values and use them in coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{13}
\def\c{\pgfmathparse{cos(5*pi/\n)}\pgfmathresult}
\def\s{\pgfmathparse{sin(5*pi/\n)}\pgfmathresult}

\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (\c,0) {B};
\node (C) at (\s,0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However when I try compiling the code above I get the following error: `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 11.`

Comment: I think this is what `\pgfmathsetmacro{macro}{expression}` is for in tikz. For instance, try to use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{cos(5*pi/\n)}`. There's more about it in Part VIII of [tikz's manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to take care of the fact that trigonometric functions in PGF take degrees and not radians. You can use, for example, `sin(pi r)`, if you want to input values in radians. Apart from that, I would suggest you use `\pgfmathsetmacro` provided by Ti*k*Z/PGF to store math results in macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{13}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{cos(5*pi/\n r)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{sin(5*pi/\n r)}

\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (\c,0) {B};
\node (C) at (\s,0) {C};

% only to show the math results
\node[above of=B, rotate=90] {\c};
\node[above of=C, rotate=90] {\s};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]